# Do something if nothing found with .find() mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm storing some data in a mongodb and accessing it with js/nodejs and mongoose. I can use .find() to find something in the database just fine, that isn't an issue. What is a problem is if there isn't something, I'd like to do something else. Currently this is what I'm trying:

```
UserModel.find({ nick: act.params }, function (err, users) {
  if (err) { console.log(err) };
  users.forEach(function (user) {
    if (user.nick === null) {
      console.log('null');
    } else if (user.nick === undefined) {
      console.log('undefined');
    } else if (user.nick === '') {
      console.log('empty');
    } else {
      console.log(user.nick);
    }
  });
});
```

None of those fire when I do something where act.params wouldn't be in the nick index. I don't get anything to console at all when this happens, but I do get user.nick to log just fine when it's actually there. I just tried to do it in reverse like this:

```
UserModel.find({ nick: act.params }, function (err, users) {
  if (err) { console.log('noooope') };
  users.forEach(function (user) {
    if (user.nick !== '') {
      console.log('null');
    } else {
      console.log('nope');
    }
  });
});
```

but this still didn't log `nope`. What am I missing here?

If it doesn't find it, it just skips everything in the find call, which is fine, except I need to do things afterwards if it isn't there that I don't want to do if it is. :/

Answer (score 122, accepted):

When there are no matches find() returns `[]`, while findOne() returns `null`. So either use:

```
Model.find( {...}, function (err, results) {
    if (err) { ... }
    if (!results.length) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

or:

```
Model.findOne( {...}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) { ... }
    if (!result) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Made this the answer for explaining the difference in what is returned between `find()` and `findOne()` and supplying the answers!

Comment: Does `// do stuff here` represent when the item is found or not?

Answer (score 9):

```
UserModel.find({ nick: act.params }, function (err, users) {
  if (err) { console.log(err) };
  if (!users.length) { //do stuff here };
  else {
    users.forEach(function (user) {
      console.log(user.nick);
    });
  }
});
```

is what I found to work.

Comment: Things must've changed since 2012. I'll try this out again tonight when I get home, and if this doesn't work and users.length does, I'll edit the answer to include it.

Answer (score 8):

I had to use:

```
 if(!users.length) { //etc }
```

to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this.**

```
if(!users) { 
    res.send({message: "User not found"});
}else {
    res.send({message: "User found"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you using `res.send(data)` or `console.log(data)` your code does return `[]` or `empty log/ empty res.send` try this code:

```
if (data === null) {
        console.log('record does not exist')
        // or do something
    }
```

example in my project

```
router.post('/updated-data', (req, res, next) => {

const userName = req.body.userName;
const newUserName = req.body.newUserName;


User.findOneAndUpdate({userName: userName}, {userName: newUserName}, {new: true}, (err, data) => {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else if (data === null || !data) {
        res.send('kullanıcı bulunamadı')
    } else {
        console.log(newUserName)
        res.send(data)
    }
})
```

*note: Other examples may be of better use.*