# How to test (by jasmine) that a collection exist in my mongo db?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, mean, jasmine-node

I'm trying to write a spec to test all the collections, I have, in my DB. I'm using Jasmine to test and working on MEAN stack.

Eg: Let says I have Staff, Client, Commission, ... et Cetera. and we wanted to test that this collection exists.

Thanks for your time and suggestion (in advance).

Answer (score 2):

Create a test using mongoose for example (https://github.com/klokoy/jasmine-node-mongo-test/blob/master/spec/test.spec.js) and check if the collection does not contain any document ([Do something if nothing found with .find() mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660587/do-something-if-nothing-found-with-find-mongoose)).

I don't know if this test is relevant, but you can do it.