# Bcrypt returns false on login

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, passwords, bcrypt

I know this question has been asked many times but I cannot find an answer to my problem both here or on github. I have a login handler which compares hashed password from db to the the one typed by the user on login. bcrypt.compare almost always returns false. I say almost because sometimes it just starts working and it always works after I register user. I am trying to find what is wrong with my code but cant figure it out. Any help is highly appreciated.

mongoose pre save

```
userModel.schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  let user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, null)
    .then(hash => {
      console.log(hash)
      user.password = hash;
      user.confirmPassword = hash;
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => res.sendStatus(404));
});
```

login handler

```
exports.loginUser = (req, res) => {
  let user = new User.model(req.body);
    User.model
      .find({email: user.email})
      .exec()
      .then(users => {
        if (!users.length) { 
          res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed - user does not exist"
          });
        } else {
          bcrypt
          .compare(req.body.password, users[0].password)
          .then(result=> {
            console.log(user.password, users[0].password)
            console.log(bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10))
            if (result) {
              const token = 
                jwt
                  .sign({ email: users[0].email, id: users[0]._id },
                  'secretKey', { expiresIn: "1h"});
              res.status(200).json({
                message: "Auth success - logged in",
                token,
                users
              });
            } else {
              res.json('not working');
            }
          })
          .catch(err => res.status(401).json({message: "Auth failed"}));
        }     
      });
};
```

register handler

```
exports.registerUser = (req, res) => {
  let user = new User.model(req.body);
  if(user.email) {
    User.model
      .find({email: user.email})
      .exec()
      .then(docs => {
        if (!docs.length) { 
          if (user.password !== user.confirmPassword) {
            return res.status(404).json('passwords do not match');
          }
          user.save(function (err, user) {
            if (err) return (err);
          });
          console.log('user saved');
          res.sendStatus(200); 
        } else {
          res.status(404).json('user exists');
        }      
      })
      .catch(err => res.sendStatus(404).json(res.body));
    } else {
      res.status(404).json('user name required');
    }
};
```

Comment: I know this probably won't help a massive amount, but I've had real success with passport.js. It bypasses a lot of the encryption etc. Would recommend.

Comment: Is there more than one record with the same email in your database?

Comment: You should be using `findOne` regardless.

Comment: No, every email is unique in my database. And I was actually thinking about implementing passport, guess I will try that.

Comment: when is use `findOne` in login handler it actually doesn't recognize my user...

Comment: Well `findOne` returns a single user, and if it doesn't exist, it returns `null`. So you would have to update your code accordingly.  `find` returns an array. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660587/do-something-if-nothing-found-with-find-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you generate a new password each time the user is saved. You should skip this though.

```
userModel.schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  let user = this;
  if(!user.isModified("password")) return next();

  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, null)
    .then(hash => {
      console.log(hash)
      user.password = hash;
      user.confirmPassword = hash;
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => res.sendStatus(404));
});
```

Just a shot in the dark though. under the assumption something got changed and this was called again, because you stated it is working sometimes.