# Nodejs & mongodb: Insert record if it does not exist. Else insert new record if changed since last record (Unhandled promise rejection)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am monitoring prices from the local supermarket and have succesfully retrieved them all in one big json. A product would be something like { id, name, price, timestamp }.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
        let productObj = productList[i];

        await db.collection("products").findOne({"id" : productObj.id}, async function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Did not find product id: " + productObj.id);
                await db.collection("products").insertOne(productObj), function(err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                };
                console.log("Done inserting");
            }
            // else insert new record if price changed
            // keep previous records for history
            console.log("Looking for product: " + result.name);
        });
    }
```

Unfortunately this give the error:

```
(node:37316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 70)
```

How do I correctly loop through the products and insert a product if it does not exist? Else I want to insert if price changed, so I cannot use the upsert functionality.

Do I just need to catch the error thrown inside the loop or what would the correct way be to handle this?

Comment: The issue is that when findOne() does not find any elements, it does not throw an error. Instead, it throws null. You would have to store the result of "await db.collection("products").findOne..." in a variable and then check if the variable is null asynchronously. This is a similar post to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660587/do-something-if-nothing-found-with-find-mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to avoid the nesting of callbacks like that. You're actually okay with simply using upsert, not sure why you consider it a problem. Here is a solution involving a total of 3 request to query and update the db without upsert:

```
const productIDs = productList.map(product => product.id);

const existingProducts = await db.collection('products').find({ 'id': { $in: productIDs }}, { 'id': 1, 'price': 1}).toArray();

const productsToAdd = productList.filter(product => !existingProducts.some(ep => ep.id === product.id));
const productsToUpdate = productList.filter(product => existingProducts.some(ep => ((ep.id === product.id) && (ep.price !== product.price))));

const insertResult = await db.collection('products').insertMany(productsToAdd);
const updateResult = await db.collection('products').bulkWrite(productsToUpdate.map(p => {
    return {
        updateOne: {
            filter: {
                id: p.id
            },
            update: {
                $set: {
                    price: price.id
                }
            }
        }
    };
}));
```

If you need to update the timestamp as well, just put it in the `update` section next to the price.

You can further optimize it by not iterating over the products twice as to differentiate candidates for insertion and update separately(you can do it in one go or simply use upsert). Also, you can put the insertions in the bulk write as well, which will reduce the requests to 2. However, I suspect neither of those optimizations are necessary for your use case.